# Changing size of an exponent with MathType on Windows 7, Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

I have the following equation:

x³+x²+1 = 0

It is using Arial 12. How could I change the size of only exponent 2, from size 12 to size 14, in all formulas of the document.
I haven't found anything on the MathType manual or tutorial.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about MathType, but you should be able to add a superscript and subscript with Word's default tools.

[image: superscript]

This allows you to change the size of exponent independently.

Comment: But I want to change all exponents 2 on the whole document. It should be a way to do it, perhaps with a simple command using VBA. How can I do it?